# UIButton: Click sound when Button is clicked in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, avfoundation

I am trying to play a sound when the UIButton: "StartButton" is clicked. However, I get an error that reads:

> Argument type 'CGPoint' does not conform to expected type 'UIFocusEnvironment'

I created the button as below and assigned a CGRect poisiton to it, and I am trying to use the touchesBeagn function to detect the location of the touch and determine if it matches the location of the Button and if so call playButtonSound() function.

This is my code in the MainMenu.swift file:

```
//  MainMenuScene.swift

import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation


let startButton:UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.roundedRect)


    class MainMenuScene: SKScene

        {

        var buttonSound = AVAudioPlayer()

        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
            background.size = self.size
            background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
            background.zPosition = 0
            self.addChild(background)

            let menuLabel1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
            menuLabel1.text = "Hit"
            menuLabel1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.45, y: self.size.height * 0.78)
            menuLabel1.fontSize = 300
            menuLabel1.fontColor = UIColor.yellow
            menuLabel1.colorBlendFactor = 1
            menuLabel1.zPosition = 1
            self.addChild(menuLabel1)

            let menuLabel2 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
            menuLabel2.text = "&"
            menuLabel2.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.55, y: self.size.height * 0.64)
            menuLabel2.fontSize = 350
            menuLabel2.fontColor = UIColor.red
            menuLabel2.colorBlendFactor = 1
            menuLabel2.zPosition = 1
            self.addChild(menuLabel2)

            let menuLabel3 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
            menuLabel3.text = "Go"
            menuLabel3.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.60, y: self.size.height * 0.52)
            menuLabel3.fontSize = 300
            menuLabel3.fontColor = UIColor.yellow
            menuLabel3.colorBlendFactor = 1
            menuLabel3.zPosition = 1
            self.addChild(menuLabel3)

            startButton.frame = CGRect(x: (self.view?.center.x)! * 0.5  , y: (self.view?.center.y)! * 1.5 , width: 200, height: 50)
            startButton.backgroundColor = .red
            startButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            startButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            startButton.clipsToBounds = true
            startButton.setTitle("Start Game", for: .normal)
            startButton.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "The Bold Font", size: 60)
            startButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.startButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.view?.addSubview(startButton)

        }

        @objc func startButtonClicked() {
            let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.reveal(with: .right , duration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)
        }



        @objc func playButtonSound(filename: String) {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "button.mp3" , withExtension: nil)
            guard let newURL = url else {
                print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
                return
            }
            do {
                buttonSound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: newURL)
                buttonSound.numberOfLoops = -1
                buttonSound.prepareToPlay()
                buttonSound.setVolume(0.50, fadeDuration: 0.1)
                buttonSound.play()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.description)
            }
        }

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                var pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

                if startButton.contains(pointOfTouch)
                {
                        playButtonSound(filename: "button.mp3")
                }



            }
        }

    }
```

What is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling the wrong `contains` method.

You are calling the method on `UIButton`, which has this signature:

```
public func contains(_ environment: UIFocusEnvironment) -> Bool
```

What you probably meant to call was the method on the button's frame:

```
if startButton.frame.contains(pointOfTouch)
```

You may want to read the docs to make sure that using the frame is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I tried it this way but the sound did not play. So what I ended up doing is to put the  : playButtonSound(filename: "button.mp3") inside the statButtonClicked() function. That did the trick but it's causing other issues that I will post a different question about.